# FULLCALENDAR - How to TRULY limit the number of events per day?

Tags: fullcalendar

I can't find the answer anywhere. How can I limit the number of simultaneous events in a time period or resource? Time wise.

Example:
I want to limit 2 simultaneous event per resources or per day. If an event start from the 8:00 to the 10:00 and another from the 9:00 to the 11:00, it's all ok. But If I try to add an event "full day", then I would have the time period from 8:00 to 9:00 that has 3 simultaneus events, and I don't want that to happen.

How can I do? I find only very custom solutions or UI solutions like eventLimits.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You have to write your own code for this. Fullcalendar can help you, it has some callbacks which help you see what is being added, and can even prevent some overlaps - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-clicking-selecting. Of course if you are saving these events to your database you will also want to add your own server-side verification code as well, since anything which happens on the client can be manipulated or bypassed by a malicious user. Your question is very broad and it's a bit unclear specifically where you're stuck or what, if anything, you've tried. Please focus it a bit more.

Comment: Thank you, my question was about an "automatic and official method", hoping to not have to do it my self.
Not a problem really, but it seems a main requirement for this kind of app. Maybe since it's opensource I'll try to study the inner code (hoping it's not too difficult) and try to add it.

Comment: You wouldn't do it via the inner code, you'd do it by hooking into the provided callbacks. In my experience of reading questions here, and use of calendars elsewhere, everyone's definition of how they want their overlaps and restrictions apply is very different and therefore having too much "core" functionality wouldn't be sensible. Also as I mentioned, a big part of validation is done server-side too, which clearly fullCalendar cannot help with. I'm not part of the fullCalendar project but it seems that they are largely thinking the same way

Comment: Therefore fullCalendar simply provides you with the information about what is happening in the calendar (i.e. what the user is currently trying to do), and you then apply your own specific rules to restrict the exact behaviour, by making use of that information.

Comment: I was thinking at something universal. If you put 4 event limits and you don't want them to overlap, you just put a check that if a 5th is inserted in a timeframe with already 4 events, it's get rejected.

I don't know how this king of functionality could have many opinions.

The server side obviously is another matter

Comment: You're assuming that everyone's requirements are always about the number of overlapping events. Sometimes there are different types of restrictions as well. But either way, either you implement it yourself, or you make a feature request to the fullCalendar team to have it added to the core features, and see if they accept it.

Comment: If you want to limit to one simultaneous event, then it's quite easy and built-in using the selectOverlap setting - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/zYRPgNQ. If you want something more complex, as you're suggesting ,then you'd probably handle the https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectAllow callback and add some logic in there to check for other events on the same day (and, optionally, resource) and see if either a) the times overlap or b) one of the events is an all-day event.

Comment: Actually the best way to avoid n overlaps is checking it in server-side. Of course you could limit some cases in client-side, but there are a lot of factors that could make it fail: It's not only about Select... it's about resizing, moving, counting on many users can be watching to the calendar in different computers at the same time... So the best way would be to make a call to the server sending the event details and then to receive the insertion/update result. If true, everything ok, and if false, rollback or error message